# Sort in mongoose throw Invalid sort value

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to sort my books and my url looks like this
`http://localhost:8085/book-metadata?sort=uniqueTimes:desc`

Then i do extract form the query sortParam `uniqueTimes:desc` and pass it to mongoose like this:

```
model
            .find({
                ...where,
                ...(dateQuery && { createdAt: { ...dateQuery } }),
            })
            .sort({ sort })
            .skip(_limit * (_page - 1))
            .limit(_limit)
            .populate(populate, populateParams)
            .select(select),
```

but it throws following error:

`TypeError: Invalid sort value: { sort: uniqueTimes:desc }`

Any idea how to fix it idk why it's happening

Comment: just try this way `.sort(...sort.split(":"))`. because it is string and it needs object or 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you sort value should be `{ uniqueTimes:-1 }` or `{ uniqueTimes:desc }`
for example  `.sort({ uniqueTimes:desc})`